# Where is my 'if-else' block going wrong?

Tags: r

I've a dataframe `df` file with the following data:

```
ID      P1  P2  Year    Month     A      B
11084   23  43  2001    April     41.9  -99.99
67985   76  12  2001    May       6.9   -9.99
11084   34  64  2001    June      -999  -99.99
34084   56  77  2001    July      NA    -99.99
11043   90  54  2001    August    NA    -99.99
23084   55  32  2001    September 50.8  -99.99
11084   77  14  2001    October   0     -99.99
54328   89  56  2001    November  -999  -99.99
```

I'm trying to add two new columns and fill 'Yes'/'No' values for the records with missing values. My expected output is:

```
ID      P1  P2  Year    Month     A      B      A_miss B_miss
11084   23  43  2001    April     41.9  -99.99  No     Yes
67985   76  12  2001    May       6.9    123    No     No
11084   34  64  2001    June      -999  -99.99  Yes    Yes
34084   56  77  2001    July      NA    -99.99  Yes    Yes
11043   90  54  2001    August    NA    -99.99  Yes    Yes
23084   55  32  2001    September 50.8  -99.99  No     Yes
11084   77  14  2001    October   0     -99.99  No     Yes
54328   89  56  2001    November  -999  -99.99  Yes    Yes
```

I'm new to R. I was trying to achieve this using simple `for` loop and `if/else` conditions in the following way:

```
for(i in length(df$A))
{
  if(df$A[i] == -999 || df$A[i] == 'NA')

    df$A_miss[i] <- 'Yes'

  else  
     df$A_miss[i] <- 'No'
}
```

I was firstly trying the loop on 'A' column, but only the `else` part was executing everytime I try and the 'No' values are being filled in the entire 'A_miss' column. I'm unable to find out why the `if` part isn't working.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Pascal - I just tried:

`for(i in length(df$A))
{
  ifelse(df$A[i] == -999.9 || is.na(na_df$A[i]),
      df$A_miss <- 'Yes',
      df$A_miss<- 'No') 
}`

And still only the `else` part is working and only 'No' is filling the column. What's wrong here?

Comment: Tried it. Still only 'No' is being filling :-(

Comment: The output is: 
      ID        P1        P2      Year     Month         A         B 
"integer" "integer" "integer" "integer"  "factor" "numeric" "numeric"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized version:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(11084L, 67985L, 11084L, 34084L, 11043L, 
23084L, 11084L, 54328L), P1 = c(23L, 76L, 34L, 56L, 90L, 55L, 
77L, 89L), P2 = c(43L, 12L, 64L, 77L, 54L, 32L, 14L, 56L), Year = c(2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L), Month = structure(c(1L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("April", "August", "July", 
"June", "May", "November", "October", "September"), class = "factor"), 
A = c(41.9, 6.9, -999, NA, NA, 50.8, 0, -999), B = c(-99.99, 
123, -99.99, -99.99, -99.99, -99.99, -99.99, -99.99), A_miss = c("No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes")), .Names = c("ID", 
"P1", "P2", "Year", "Month", "A", "B", "A_miss"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")

df$A_miss <- ifelse(df$A == -999 | is.na(df$A), "yes", "no")
df$B_miss <- ifelse(df$B == -99.99 | is.na(df$B), "yes", "no")

     ID P1 P2 Year     Month      A      B A_miss B_miss
1 11084 23 43 2001     April   41.9 -99.99     no    yes
2 67985 76 12 2001       May    6.9 123.00     no     no
3 11084 34 64 2001      June -999.0 -99.99    yes    yes
4 34084 56 77 2001      July     NA -99.99    yes    yes
5 11043 90 54 2001    August     NA -99.99    yes    yes
6 23084 55 32 2001 September   50.8 -99.99     no    yes
7 11084 77 14 2001   October    0.0 -99.99     no    yes
8 54328 89 56 2001  November -999.0 -99.99    yes    yes
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work either. Still only the `else` part's 'no' values are going into every record irrespective of the `if` condition.

Comment: Surprisingly it worked fine for the B_miss column but not for A_miss. Any ideas there?

Comment: I tried this and it works fine for me but you could try to do the A_miss part like this: `df$A_miss <- ifelse(df$A %in% c(-999,NA), "yes", "no")`

Comment: I just had a nother look at your example data and I realized the negative values are not always the same. Is this a typo or is it actually true that you have different negative values and all negative values should be considered as missing? In that case the two lines above should be changed to: `df$A_miss <- ifelse(df$A < 0 | is.na(df$A), "yes", "no")
df$B_miss <- ifelse(df$B < 0 | is.na(df$B), "yes", "no")`

Comment: Adjusted the many negative values in the original dataset. Worked correctly now.  Thank you so much all of you for the help :))))

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is not correctly defined. This one works:

```
for (i in 1:length(df$A)) {
    if(df$A[i] == -999 || is.na(df$A[i]) )
        df$A_miss[i] <- 'Yes'

    else  
        df$A_miss[i] <- 'No'
}
```

The limit should be set as `(i in 1:length(df$A))`, and not as `(i in length(df$A)`. Hope this helps.

PS: As you can see, the important correction pointed out by @Pascal has been implemented here.

PPS: The version below should be much faster than your code with the `for` loop:

```
df$A_miss <- 'No'
df$A_miss[which(df$A==-999 | is.na(df$A)] <- 'Yes'
```

(I just noticed that this solution is very similar to the one that had been suggested earlier by @Daniel Fischer)

Comment: `R` is vectorized and `FOR` loops are usually unnecessary, lengthy, and slow. You may want to learn about alternative ways to treat such problems.

Comment: Just a small doubt. I'm trying your correction `1:length(df$A)` right now and the command is still running.. I've 1 Million records. So, does it usually take this long? It didn't take this long before for those codes in the above answers. Is this a normal behaviour? (Similar thing happened when I was using `while` loop yesterday.)

Comment: You weren't actually performing a loop before - you only looked at the last element. Yes, `FOR` loops are terribly slow in `R` on large datasets. Others have pointed out different solutions without loops that should be significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this, without any loop or if clause:

```
    df$A[(df$A==-999)|(is.na(df$A))] <- "yes"
    df$A[df$A!="yes"] <- "no"
```

Comment: But I want to put the 'yes' and 'no' values in A_miss column and not in the A itself. How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe quick and dirty would be to run first `df$A_miss <- df$A` and then change in my code all `df$A` to `df$A_miss`

Comment: Do it all in one go `df[paste0(vars,"_miss")] <- lapply(df[vars], function(x) (is.na(x)) | (x %in% c(-999,-99,-99.99)) )`

Comment: @Daneil - When I tried the quick and dirty way, the first line didn't put "yes" in the column df$A_miss :-(

Answer (score 0):

Using the which command might increase the speed of the process:

```
df$A_miss[which(df$A==-999 | is.na(df$A))] <- 'Yes'
df$A_miss[which(df$A_miss!='Yes')] <- 'no'
```